# Overflow icon displaying twice, in actionbar (top) and android navigation bar (bottom)

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, overflow

I have a problem where there is an icon that shows the options menu on my actionbar and another in the navigation bar.
Both works and calls the menu but i want to show only one.
What to do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Say Goodbye to the Menu Button blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), the action overflow button for legacy apps appears if you are not targeting a newer version of Android:

> - If you set either `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` to 11 or higher, the system will not add the legacy overflow button.
> - Otherwise, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running on Android 3.0 or higher.
> - The only exception is that if you set `minSdkVersion` to 10 or lower, set `targetSdkVersion` to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use `ActionBar`, the system *will* add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.

You should always target the latest SDK version that you have tested your app on (which preferably is the newest released version) - setting your `targetSdkVersion` to greater than 13 is the easiest way to remove the legacy action overflow button.

Comment: Thank you. It happens cause i was with target 10 on my manifest launching in my real nexus 4.